# Chrome Remote Desktop package not compatible with Brave web browser on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: ssh, google-chrome, remote-desktop

Good day Ubuntu Community! I remotely log into other desktops, using the browser extension for Chrome Remote Desktop  on Brave, but sharing my own screen proves to be more difficult. I understand that installing and using the Chrome web browser directly might resolve the matter. If that is the only way about it, I will have to go with it, but want to make sure before I do. I've tried other remote desktop servers like Rust, TeamView and AnyDesk, but found that Chrome Remote Desktop provides the best free cross-platform support.

I've downloaded and installed the .deb file both via the Software Installer and the Terminal (removing the packages in-between installs). My current package was installed via a temporary .deb file, using promps provided by [Helpwire](https://www.helpwire.app/blog/chrome-remote-desktop-linux/). I also know about methods like: "sudo apt-get install package_name", (after running the "sudo apt-get update" prompt and checking for available packages). I just finished a Udemy course by Ziyad Yehia on the Linux command line, [Linux Mastery](https://www.udemy.com/course/linux-mastery/). All this is still very new to me.

I understand that trying different installations is probably missing the obvious solution that Chrome Remote Desktop needs the Chrome web browser to run? An article on [Computer World](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3230909/chrome-remote-desktop-access-remote-computer-easily.html) clearly states this, but I perhaps naively thought since I'm running the Google search engine on Brave, that it should work. I figure that having Chrome web browser installed on my Linux machine (just) to run this package probably isn't that cumbersome and I can carry on with other things again.

I quickly ran a search for documentation on Chrome Remote Desktop and found the following explanation on a site from [AnyViewer](https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/chrome-remote-desktop-without-chrome-0427.html#:%7E:text=Chrome%20Remote%20Desktop%20does%20indeed,to%20establish%20the%20remote%20connection.): "Chrome Remote Desktop does indeed need Chrome to be running since it is specifically designed to work with the Chrome browser. It utilizes the underlying infrastructure and features provided by Chrome to establish the remote connection." This site is directed more towards gaining a following for AnyDesk, but cements my understanding that I need Chrome for Chrome Remote Desktop.

I am new to Linux, so please help me where you see fit. I apologise that this question might not belong entirely on this forum.  It is probably a very obvious matter also, but being a complete novice when it comes to the real workings of computers, operating systems and programs (or packages), I try to scratch a bit deeper in order to build my understanding. I have a massive opportunity to go into programming for software development, though self guided learning. Working on Linux is a wonderful way to learn! Thank you for your time and consideration!

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of the shields before attempting to use Chrome Remote Desktop? Beyond that I would say reaching out on the Brave forums might yield a better result. Good luck!

Comment: Hello, Robby1212. Thank you very much for your comment. I am rather going to use Chrome, as I believe the strength of Brave is in its shields and security. I will commit to it again soon and post the result. All the best!

Comment: Installing Chrome did the trick. No problems, Whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to simply install the Chrome web browser. Not only was the Chrome Remote Desktop browser extension already linked, but the "share your screen" functionality was already set up as well. Many thanks. I am learning!